# Roll apply for partial time series in R

Tags: r, rollapply

Given

```
z <- zoo(c(1:10))
```

I want to be be able to aggregate to the following:

```
> z
 4  8  10 
 10 26 19
```

I have tried the following using rollapply but to no avail:

```
> rollapply(zoo(c(1:10)), width = 4, FUN = "sum", by = 4, partial = TRUE, align = "right")
 1  5  9 
 1 14 30 
> rollapply(zoo(c(1:10)), width = 4, FUN = "sum", by = 4, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
 1  5  9 
10 26 19 
> rollapply(zoo(c(1:10)), width = 4, FUN = "sum", by = 4, partial = TRUE, align = "center")
 1  5  9 
 6 22 27
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The second looks most promising but I would have to customize a lag?

Answer (score 1):

The `partial` argument always applies to both ends; however, one can specify the width for each element separately by using a vector for the `width` argument and then subset it yourself instead of using `by`:

```
library(zoo)

# inputs
z <- zoo(1:10)
k <- 4    

n <- length(z)
w <- rep(1:k, length = n)  # 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 
ok <- w == k | seq(n) == n  # F F F T F F F T F T

rollapplyr(z, w, sum)[ok]
```

giving:

```
 4  8 10 
10 26 19
```

**2)** We could use `align = "left"` and then fix up the times (using `ok` from above):

```
r <- rollapply(z, k, by = k, sum, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
time(r) <- time(z)[ok]
```

**3)** This could be done using `aggregate.zoo` (using `ok` from above):

```
tt <- na.locf(replace(time(z), !ok, NA), fromLast = TRUE)  # 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 10 10
aggregate(z, tt, sum)
```